# Socket error in messaging program

Tags: python, python-2.7, sockets

I am currently trying to make my own private messaging program for just me and my friend to use and I keep getting an error with the "s.listen(1)" part of the client chat program, I do not understand the reason for which I am experiencing and I have tried many different things to figure out what is wrong.

The error is:

```
    Unhandled exception in thread started by <function GetConnected at 0x027E42F0>
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "client.pyw", line 84, in GetConnected
    s.listen(1)
  File "<string>", line 1, in listen
socket.error: (10022, 'Invalid argument')
```

These are the 3 files of code:

```
from Tkinter import *
from socket import *
import urllib
import re
import pygame
import win32gui

def getmixerargs():
    pygame.mixer.init()
    freq, size, chan = pygame.mixer.get_init()
    return freq, size, chan
def initMixer():
    BUFFER = 3072  # audio buffer size, number of samples since pygame 1.8.
    FREQ, SIZE, CHAN = getmixerargs()
    pygame.mixer.init(FREQ, SIZE, CHAN, BUFFER)
def playsound(soundfile):
    pygame.init()
    pygame.mixer.init()
    sound = pygame.mixer.Sound(soundfile)
    clock = pygame.time.Clock()
    sound.play()
    while pygame.mixer.get_busy():
        clock.tick(1000)        
def playmusic(soundfile):
    pygame.init()
    pygame.mixer.init()
    clock = pygame.time.Clock()
    pygame.mixer.music.load(soundfile)
    pygame.mixer.music.play()
    while pygame.mixer.music.get_busy():
        clock.tick(1000)
def stopmusic():
    pygame.mixer.music.stop()

#HOW TO PLAY SONG:
initMixer()
#playmusic(filename)



def FlashMyWindow(title):
    ID = win32gui.FindWindow(None, title)
    win32gui.FlashWindow(ID,True)

def FlashMyWindow2(title2):
    ID2 = win32gui.FindWindow(None, title2)
    win32gui.FlashWindow(ID2,True)    

def GetExternalIP():
    url = "http://checkip.dyndns.org"
    request = urllib.urlopen(url).read()
    return str(re.findall(r"\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}.\d{1,3}", request))

def GetInternalIP():
    return str(gethostbyname(getfqdn()))

def FilteredMessage(EntryText):
    EndFiltered = ''
    for i in range(len(EntryText)-1,-1,-1):
        if EntryText[i]!='\n':
            EndFiltered = EntryText[0:i+1]
            break
    for i in range(0,len(EndFiltered), 1):
            if EndFiltered[i] != "\n":
                    return EndFiltered[i:]+'\n'
    return ''

def LoadConnectionInfo(ChatLog, EntryText):
    if EntryText != '':
        ChatLog.config(state=NORMAL)
        if ChatLog.index('end') != None:
            ChatLog.insert(END, EntryText+'\n')
            ChatLog.config(state=DISABLED)
            ChatLog.yview(END)
def getName():
   x = GetExternalIP()
def LoadMyEntry(ChatLog, EntryText):
    if EntryText != '':
        ChatLog.config(state=NORMAL)
        if ChatLog.index('end') != None:
                if getName() is not ("96.231.3." + range(1, 1000)):
                    name = "Conor"
                else:
                    name = "Ceci"
                LineNumber = float(ChatLog.index('end'))-1.0
                ChatLog.insert(END, name + ": " + EntryText)
                ChatLog.tag_add(name, LineNumber, LineNumber+0.4)
                ChatLog.tag_config(name, foreground="#FF8000", font=("Arial", 12, "bold"))
                ChatLog.config(state=DISABLED)
                ChatLog.yview(END)


def LoadOtherEntry(ChatLog, EntryText):
    if EntryText != '':
        ChatLog.config(state=NORMAL)
        if ChatLog.index('end') is not None:
            try:
                LineNumber = float(ChatLog.index('end'))-1.0
            except:
                pass
            def getName():
                if GetInternalIP() is not ("96.231.3." + range(1, 1000)):
                    name2 = "Ceci"
                else:
                    name2 = "Conor"
                getName()
                ChatLog.insert(END, name2 + ": " + EntryText)
                ChatLog.tag_add(name2, LineNumber, LineNumber+0.6)
                ChatLog.tag_config(name2, foreground="#04B404", font=("Arial", 12, "bold"))
                ChatLog.config(state=DISABLED)
                ChatLog.yview(END)
```

File 2:

```
import thread
from ChatFns import *

# ---------------------------------------------------#
# ---------INITIALIZE CONNECTION VARIABLES-----------#
# ---------------------------------------------------#
# Initiate socket and bind port to host PC
WindowTitle = 'Messenger v1 - Host'
s = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM)
HOST = gethostname()
PORT = 801111
conn = ''
s.bind((HOST, PORT))


# ---------------------------------------------------#
# ------------------ MOUSE EVENTS -------------------#
# ---------------------------------------------------#
def ClickAction():
    # Write message to chat window
    EntryText = FilteredMessage(EntryBox.get("0.0", END))
    LoadMyEntry(ChatLog, EntryText)

    # Scroll to the bottom of chat windows
    ChatLog.yview(END)

    # Erase previous message in Entry Box
    EntryBox.delete("0.0", END)

    # Send my message to all others
    conn.sendall(EntryText)


# ---------------------------------------------------#
# ----------------- KEYBOARD EVENTS -----------------#
# ---------------------------------------------------#
def PressAction(event):
    EntryBox.config(state=NORMAL)
    ClickAction()


def DisableEntry(event):
    EntryBox.config(state=DISABLED)


# ---------------------------------------------------#
# -----------------GRAPHICS MANAGEMENT---------------#
# ---------------------------------------------------#

# Create a window
base = Tk()
base.title(WindowTitle)
base.geometry("400x500")
base.resizable(width=FALSE, height=FALSE)

# Create a Chat window
ChatLog = Text(base, bd=0, bg="white", height="8", width="50", font="Arial", )
ChatLog.insert(END, "Waiting for your partner to connect..\n")
ChatLog.config(state=DISABLED)

# Bind a scrollbar to the Chat window
scrollbar = Scrollbar(base, command=ChatLog.yview, cursor="heart")
ChatLog['yscrollcommand'] = scrollbar.set

# Create the Button to send message
SendButton = Button(base, font=30, text="Send", width="12", height=5,
                    bd=0, bg="#FFBF00", activebackground="#FACC2E",
                    command=ClickAction)

# Create the box to enter message
EntryBox = Text(base, bd=0, bg="white", width="29", height="5", font="Arial")
EntryBox.bind("<Return>", DisableEntry)
EntryBox.bind("<KeyRelease-Return>", PressAction)

# Place all components on the screen
scrollbar.place(x=376, y=6, height=386)
ChatLog.place(x=6, y=6, height=386, width=370)
EntryBox.place(x=128, y=401, height=90, width=265)
SendButton.place(x=6, y=401, height=90)

# ---------------------------------------------------#
# ----------------CONNECTION MANAGEMENT--------------#
# ---------------------------------------------------#
def GetConnected():
    s.listen(1)
    global conn
    conn, addr = s.accept()
    LoadConnectionInfo(ChatLog, 'Connected with: ' + str(
        addr) + '\n---------------------------------------------------------------')

    while 1:
        try:
            data = conn.recv(1024)
            LoadOtherEntry(ChatLog, data)
            if base.focus_get() == None:
                FlashMyWindow(WindowTitle)
                playsound('notif.wav')
        except:
            LoadConnectionInfo(ChatLog, '\n [ Your partner has disconnected ]\n [ Waiting for him to connect..] \n  ')
            GetConnected()

    conn.close()


thread.start_new_thread(GetConnected, ())

base.mainloop()
```

File 3:

```
import thread
from ChatFns import *

# ---------------------------------------------------#
# ---------INITIALIZE CONNECTION VARIABLES-----------#
# ---------------------------------------------------#
# Initiate socket and bind port to host PC
WindowTitle = 'Messenger v1 - Client'
HOST = "(My local ip would normally be here)"
PORT = 801111
s = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM)


# ---------------------------------------------------#
# ------------------ MOUSE EVENTS -------------------#
# ---------------------------------------------------#
def ClickAction():
    # Write message to chat window
    EntryText = FilteredMessage(EntryBox.get("0.0", END))
    LoadMyEntry(ChatLog, EntryText)

    # Scroll to the bottom of chat windows
    ChatLog.yview(END)

    # Erase previous message in Entry Box
    EntryBox.delete("0.0", END)

    # Send my message to all others
    conn.sendall(EntryText)


# ---------------------------------------------------#
# ----------------- KEYBOARD EVENTS -----------------#
# ---------------------------------------------------#
def PressAction(event):
    EntryBox.config(state=NORMAL)
    ClickAction()


def DisableEntry(event):
    EntryBox.config(state=DISABLED)


# ---------------------------------------------------#
# -----------------GRAPHICS MANAGEMENT---------------#
# ---------------------------------------------------#

# Create a window
base = Tk()
base.title(WindowTitle)
base.geometry("400x500")
base.resizable(width=FALSE, height=FALSE)

# Create a Chat window
ChatLog = Text(base, bd=0, bg="white", height="8", width="50", font="Arial", )
ChatLog.insert(END, "Waiting for your partner to connect..\n")
ChatLog.config(state=DISABLED)

# Bind a scrollbar to the Chat window
scrollbar = Scrollbar(base, command=ChatLog.yview, cursor="heart")
ChatLog['yscrollcommand'] = scrollbar.set

# Create the Button to send message
SendButton = Button(base, font=30, text="Send", width="12", height=5,
                    bd=0, bg="#FFBF00", activebackground="#FACC2E",
                    command=ClickAction)

# Create the box to enter message
EntryBox = Text(base, bd=0, bg="white", width="29", height="5", font="Arial")
EntryBox.bind("<Return>", DisableEntry)
EntryBox.bind("<KeyRelease-Return>", PressAction)

# Place all components on the screen
scrollbar.place(x=376, y=6, height=386)
ChatLog.place(x=6, y=6, height=386, width=370)
EntryBox.place(x=128, y=401, height=90, width=265)
SendButton.place(x=6, y=401, height=90)


# ---------------------------------------------------#
# ----------------CONNECTION MANAGEMENT--------------#
# ---------------------------------------------------#
def GetConnected():
    s.listen(1)
    global conn
    conn, addr = s.accept()
    LoadConnectionInfo(ChatLog, 'Connected with: ' + str(
        addr) + '\n---------------------------------------------------------------')

    while 1:
        try:
            data = conn.recv(1024)
            LoadOtherEntry(ChatLog, data)
            if base.focus_get() == None:
                FlashMyWindow(WindowTitle)
                playsound('notif.wav')
        except:
            LoadConnectionInfo(ChatLog, '\n [ Your partner has disconnected ]\n [ Waiting for him to connect..] \n  ')
            GetConnected()

    conn.close()


thread.start_new_thread(GetConnected, ())

base.mainloop()
```

Comment: Can you try making a small, isolated, working example of the problem occuring? I bet 95% of that code is completely irrelevant.

Comment: Errm. Well. Welcome to StackOverflow. You should be providing a MVCE http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve. That lot doesn't look exactly minimal, and also you don't say which of the three files is which, so I don't know where to look for the line where the error occurs. Have you tried goggling for, say: _python socket server_ I'm sure there are lots of examples on stackoverflow.com you could start by learning from. A productive way of developing a new program is often to do it a little bit at a time, so you solve one problem at once.

Comment: What port number are you trying to listen on? Is that possible?

Answer (score 0):

Port numbers are 0-65535 (or at least they were in the IPv4 days, nut sure about v6).

To stand any chance of getting this to work you should change:

```
PORT = 801111
```

to something in the range 0-65535 which isn't already in use and preferably which isn't already well-known for an existing protocol/application, e.g.:

```
PORT = 8011
```

Comment: Did I answer your question?